# Can I overclock i7 2670qm?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, overclocking

I have an i7 2670qm CPU and I'm wondering if I could overclock it. What is the risk and what could happen to the CPU or other hardware devices?
Is there anyone who has overclocked this specific CPU before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I could overclock an i7 2670qm.

The i7 2670qm is not an unlocked part.  This means you will be unable to modify what the base frequency will run at.  This effectively means you will be unable to overclock the CPU.

> What is the risk and what could happen to the CPU or other hardware devices?

Damage due to overclocking is not covered under your warranty through Intel.

Source: [Intel® Core™ i7-2670QM Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/53469/intel-core-i7-2670qm-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz.html)

Comment: Even if you could overclock this particular processor, due to it being a mobile processor, you wouldn't be overclock it a great deal.  You would have been luck to get maybe an additional 200 Mhz out of that processor.

Comment: @AlirezaA2F - That will happen automatically (unless you have specifically disabled it within the firmware).

Comment: How can I get the Max Turbo Frequency which is 3.1 GHz?